# DynamoDB PutItem attribute_not_exist conditional keeps failing

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to put a bunch of items on DynamoDB. I have a CSV file with four columns, and I wanted the data inside the rows to correspond to each other when I append them into DynamoDB. Note that there are multiple `ItemId`s with the same `ItemType`, hence the conditional expression.

The table is set up in a way that the `partition key` is the `ItemId`, while the `sort key` is the `ItemType`.

My code looks like this:

```
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    table = dynamodb.Table(table)
    
    t_df = df[df['product'] == product_category]

    itemId = t_df['id'].tolist()
    transactionDetail = t_df['transaction_detail'].tolist()

    try:
        for itemIds, details in itertools.zip_longest(itemId, transactionDetail):
            table.put_item(
                Item={
                    'ItemId': itemIds,
                    'ItemType': details,
                    'ProductCategory': product_category
                },
                ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(ItemId) OR attribute_not_exists(ItemType)'
            )
        
        print("Transaction Type Added!", ['HTTPStatusCode'])
    
    except ClientError as ce:
        print(ce)
```

Yet I keep getting this:

```
An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the PutItem operation: The conditional request failed
```

And when I look at the DynamoDB table, there is a ton of missing data. I don't understand why the conditional is failing. Isn't it supposed to be able to put in data since both conditions aren't always satisfied? Can anybody point me to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you do a `ConditionalExpression` you’re going to get that Exception if the condition isn’t satisfied. Condition satisfied? Put operation happens. Condition not satisfied? Get this exception.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't clear in my post. When I check my DynamoDB database, it's also not completely populated by all the rows taken from the csv file. @hunterhacker

Comment: Pick a row that didn’t load, test it in isolation.